# Upgraded to 5.3.2 from 5.3.1, now warning Cron not running - log shows it is at 10 minute intervals - Ignore?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, cron

Running on Wordpress 4.8.7. No problem with Cron on 5.3.1, but right after upgrading we're getting warning that cron is not running.
    "Cron Not Running-
Last cron run at July 28th, 2018 3:20 PM."

```
Here is crontab entry, sanitized:
```

*/10    *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home2/xxxxxx/newarksymphony.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s www.newarksymphony.org -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxx -e Job -a execute

```
Scheduled jobs log shows that jobs are indeed running every 10 minutes.
```

==================================

2018-07-29 15:40:02 Civirules cron
Entity: Civirules Action: Cron

Summary
Starting execution of Civirules cron
Details
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
Full message:

Starting execution of Civirules cron

==================================

2018-07-29 15:30:02 Civirules cron
Entity: Civirules Action: Cron

Summary
Finished execution of Civirules cron with result: Success (a:0:{})
Details
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
Full message:

Finished execution of Civirules cron with result: Success (a:0:{})

=================================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check MYSQL and PHP are using the same timezone? This sometimes happens when both are running on different timezones.

You can find a solution for similar sorts of issues [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25825/155).

Comment: I checked and PHP was on US Eastern and MYSQL  "system_time_zone" was Central, one hour off.  I'm on shared hosting and don't have control over the latter.  But I'm trying a solution (in civicrm.settings.php)  based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql  There are a few time_zone variables in SQL.  How can I be sure what is really in use?

Comment: Found a way to easily look at the PHP vs SQL times.  In the table log_civicrm_job the column "last_run" show the job run time, based on PHP, and "log_date" shows the log entry time based on SQL server.  In my case the times are still off by 1 hour even though I have this in civicrm.settings.php:
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=realdbname', 'dbuser','password');
$db->exec("SET time_zone='-4:00';");       But the cron running error has gone away even with the timezones off by an hour.